# Earlier questions not tied to my account

Tags: support, merge-accounts, multiple-accounts

I found around half a dozen posts from me, done back in 2012 ish, that are not tied into my current account. How can a link be established?  Reading them it's obvious they're written by me, and not another 'Tim', of which there were several over the years!